# How do I treat this kind of data to pass to Laravel blade?

Tags: laravel, soap, stdclass

I´m doing a SOAP call and it is working just fine. The response is this kind of data but somehow, I am not able to handle it.
Tried to json_encode, json_decode, ->toArray, ->toJson, but NOTHING works.

This is my dd($response);

```
{#200 ▼
  +"ExtratoContaCorrente": {#201 ▼
    +"NOME-CLIENTE": "DOE, JONH"
    +"CODIGO-GRUPO": "00000"
    +"NUMERO-COTA": 00
    +"NOME-LOGRADOURO": "RODRIGO PEREIRA JUNIOR"
    +"NUMERO-LOGRADOURO": "519"
    +"BAIRRO": "PRESIDENTE ROOSEVELT"
    +"CIDADE": "UBERLANDIA"
    +"UF": "MG"
    +"CEP": "00000000"
    +"NUMERO-TELEFONE": "000 00000000"
    +"CODIGO-BEM": "6156"
    +"VALOR-BEM": 12000.0
    +"PERC-TOTAL-PAGO": 31.7396
    +"VALOR-QUITACAO": 10090.62
    +"PERC-TOAL-PAGAR": 0.5546
    +"PARCELAS-PAGAS": {#207 ▼
      +"PARCELA-PAGA": {#208 ▼
        +"NUMERO-PARCELA": 17
        +"DATA-VENCIMENTO": "20190108"
        +"DATA-PAGAMENTO": "20190108"
        +"VALOR-PARCELA": 189.1
        +"HITORICO-PARCELA": ""
        +"PERC-PAGO": 0.5546
      }
    }
    +"PARCELAS-PENDENTES": {#209 ▼
      +"PARCELAS-PENDENTES": {#210 ▼
        +"NUMERO-PARCELA": 5
        +"DATA-VENCIMENTO": "20190208"
        +"VALOR-PARCELA": 203.71
        +"PERC-PENDENTE": 0.5546
      }
      +"VALOR-TOTAL-PENDENTE": 203.71
      +"PERC-TOTAL-PENDENTE": 0.5546
    }
    +"PROXIMA-ASSEMBLEIA": {#211 ▼
      +"DATA-ASSEMB": "20190212"
      +"DATA-SORTEIO": "20190209"
      +"HORARIO-ASSEMB": "1600"
      +"ENDERESO-ASSEMB": "GOVERNADOR RONDON PACHECO  "
      +"BAIRRO-ASSEMB": "VILA POVOA"
      +"CIDADE-ASSEMB": "UBERLANDIA"
      +"UF-ASSEMB": "MG"
    }
    +"RESULT-ULTIMA-ASSEMB": {#212 ▼
      +"DATA-REALIZACAO": "20190111"
      +"COTAS-CONTEMP-SORTEIO": array:2 [▼
        0 => {#213 ▼
          +"NUMERO-COTA": 346
        }
        1 => {#214 ▼
          +"NUMERO-COTA": 434
        }
      ]
      +"COTAS-CONTEMP-LANCE": array:16 [▼
        0 => {#215 ▼
          +"NUMERO-COTA": 254
          +"PERC-LANCE": 42.8571
          +"QDE-PARCELAS": 23.142
        }
        1 => {#216 ▼
          +"NUMERO-COTA": 338
          +"PERC-LANCE": 40.0
          +"QDE-PARCELAS": 23.2
        }
        2 => {#217 ▼
          +"NUMERO-COTA": 348
          +"PERC-LANCE": 41.0
          +"QDE-PARCELAS": 24.599
        }
        3 => {#218 ▼
          +"NUMERO-COTA": 369
          +"PERC-LANCE": 35.72
          +"QDE-PARCELAS": 20.36
        }
        4 => {#219 ▼
          +"NUMERO-COTA": 429
          +"PERC-LANCE": 30.0
          +"QDE-PARCELAS": 18.0
        }
        5 => {#220 ▼
          +"NUMERO-COTA": 445
          +"PERC-LANCE": 30.0
          +"QDE-PARCELAS": 18.0
        }
        6 => {#221 ▼
          +"NUMERO-COTA": 467
          +"PERC-LANCE": 38.0
          +"QDE-PARCELAS": 22.799
        }
        7 => {#222 ▼
          +"NUMERO-COTA": 493
          +"PERC-LANCE": 37.8405
          +"QDE-PARCELAS": 22.704
        }
        8 => {#223 ▼
          +"NUMERO-COTA": 513
          +"PERC-LANCE": 41.6667
          +"QDE-PARCELAS": 23.75
        }
        9 => {#224 ▼
          +"NUMERO-COTA": 572
          +"PERC-LANCE": 37.0
          +"QDE-PARCELAS": 20.35
        }
        10 => {#225 ▼
          +"NUMERO-COTA": 577
          +"PERC-LANCE": 40.0
          +"QDE-PARCELAS": 14.4
        }
        11 => {#226 ▼
          +"NUMERO-COTA": 707
          +"PERC-LANCE": 40.55
          +"QDE-PARCELAS": 20.275
        }
        12 => {#227 ▼
          +"NUMERO-COTA": 709
          +"PERC-LANCE": 40.0
          +"QDE-PARCELAS": 23.999
        }
        13 => {#228 ▼
          +"NUMERO-COTA": 779
          +"PERC-LANCE": 45.0
          +"QDE-PARCELAS": 16.2
        }
        14 => {#229 ▼
          +"NUMERO-COTA": 925
          +"PERC-LANCE": 47.0
          +"QDE-PARCELAS": 25.85
        }
        15 => {#230 ▼
          +"NUMERO-COTA": 929
          +"PERC-LANCE": 45.0611
          +"QDE-PARCELAS": 24.783
        }
      ]
    }
    +"CODIGO-RETORNO": 0
    +"DESCRICAO-RETORNO": ""
  }
}
```

Is this an object with arrays? Just can tell...

I am totally unable to treat that data to pass to blade. Never have to pass through this! Anyone?

Comment: what does dd((obj)$response); give you?

Comment: I´ve changed to:

```
$response = (array) $this->service->ROS_ExtratoContaCorrente($params);
            return $response;
```
The response now is a big array

Comment: So it's the same, right?

Comment: dd((obj)$response) gives an error:
syntax error, unexpected '$response' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')'
but dd($response) it´s the same!

Comment: you're clearly missing a ;  from the error. I think this might be a soap response aka a form of XML. There are packages that deal with that

Comment: Ok, I´ll look into it!